# Why character in StringBuild does not change?

Tags: java

The character must be entered from the console to change to lowercase letters on this line. But it displays the same word and the symbol does not change.

```
public class Task {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(requestString());
        char symbol = requestSymbol().charAt(0);
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            if (sb.charAt(i) == symbol) {
                sb.setCharAt(i, sb.charAt(Character.toUpperCase(i)));
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of entries: " + count);
        System.out.println("Converted string: " + sb);
    }

    static String requestString() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter string:");
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    static String requestSymbol() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the symbol:");
        return scanner.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the line:

```java
sb.setCharAt(i, sb.charAt(Character.toUpperCase(i)));
```

It should be:

```java
sb.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(symbol));
```

Comment: *to change to lowercase letters*